# Display Facebook "Like" button when user is not logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, integration

Right now the "Like" button is not rendered if the Facebook page it links to has restrictions based upon age, country or content-type. The button only appears if the user is logged in to Facebook and his profile allows him to see the page.

The restrictions need to stay in place, but I want to display the like button along side the number of likes and have it prompt the user to login to Facebook instead of the button not showing at all.

I don't want to create hacks around the widget (if that's even possible) so is there a configuration or something to have the button show up even if the user is not logged in?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: If you have an application id, yes, you can use [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) callback and check if response equals to `unknown` (the user is not logged in) but you can't check age, country ...